# type hint for fixed length iterables

Tags: python, type-hinting

I have a function which takes fixed length lists or tuples and I was wondering how I should type hint them. So, the function signature is:

```
def order_pts(pt1: Iterable, pt2: Iterable, pt3: Iterable)
```

Where each of these are basically 2-dimensional tuples/list. I can annotate them as `Iterable` but I am not sure how to specify that these are 2 element collections?

Comment: Is the question about throwing error if these tuples/lists are not 2d?

Comment: 2-D tuples/lists are not the same to fixed length tuples/lists. Can you please write down an example of an input argument?

Comment: @aerijman He is talking about type hinting not about type asserting.